# Is it possible to create an excel Pivot Table as template that updates when the sheet data changes?

Tags: java, excel

I'm working on a project where my data source (sheet) changes weekly. I need to create a pivot table with certain filters, I would like to know if it is possible to create an excel template with default filters. The number of rows change every week but the number of columns is the same.

I'm also trying to create the Pivot Table with apache Poi, but the problem is that it only allows to create default pivot tables.

My plan is to create with Java a new sheet of data, every week, into an existing excel file (template) and then, if is possible, in another sheet generate the pivot table with some filters.

Answer (score 1):

**SINGLE FILE**

You don't need an Excel template to do this:

- create the data sheet and the pivot table sheet for the first week, and set all filters and everything you need
- each week from your code add and fill the new data sheet, then copy the original pivot table sheet to a new one
- update the pivot table source property to reference the right data sheet
- execute (manually or programmatically) an Update of the new pivot

**MULTIPLE FILES (one for each week)**

- Create a workbook as before, then save it as a template (.xltx).
- From your code create a new workbook based on the template and update the data sheet.
- Update the pivot table source property to reflect the number of data rows you created (alternatively you may set it once and for all to consider the whole columns, e.g. `$A:$H` instead of `$A1:$H1234`, but you will always have an "empty" row in your pivot)
- Update the pivot